# Dropdown buttons?

Tags: html, css

As you might've heard on my other question, **Margin-Right on CSS not working**, I am re-creating my school's website home page for the fun of it. I am pretty far on the Website and I need some CSS and HTML code with dropdown buttons. on one of the dropdowns, I am wanting the links inside to be side by side, like 7 rows and 2 columns, for 14 links. I literally have no idea how to make them like that because they keep lining up by 14 rows 1 column My CSS and HTML code for the buttons are as follows

```css
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #2E64FE;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #2E2EFE;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">School Office</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Principles Office</a>
    <a href="#">School Nurse</a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">District office</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">SuperIndentents office</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Departments</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Buissness Office</a>
    <a href="#">Facilities</a>
    <a href="#">Food Service</a>
    <a href="#">Human Resources</a><a href="#">Transportation</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Staff</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Teachers</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Board</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the Teachers dropdown, I would like it to be rows and columns, not just rows.

Comment: Fiddle of current code: https://jsfiddle.net/pb10k9hj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the links up into two separate `div` blocks within the dropdown container, and set them to `display:inline-block;`:

```
<div class="one-side">
 <a href="#">Link 1</a>
 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div class="one-side">
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one-side{display:inline-block;}
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pb10k9hj/1/

Comment: Here's the same sort of thing using Bootstrap columns: https://jsfiddle.net/pb10k9hj/2/

Comment: Why Thank you, Mr A.Sharma

Comment: Glad to have helped. Accept the answer when possible!